# display results on query basis in Codeigniter with Pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have a table of products. I need to display all the products. I am fetching results on different conditions.

```
create table `products` (
    `id` double ,
    `category_id` double ,
    `subcategory_id` double ,
    `product_name` varchar (765),
    `product_description` varchar (765),
    `product_viewed` varchar (765),
    `sale_wanted` tinyint (2),
    `added_date` datetime ,
    `updated_date` datetime ,
);
```

I need to diplay the results like this

```
1. The latest products (use of added date)
2. Most Wanted (Sorting by sale_wanted 1 for sale , 2 for wanted)
3. Most Viewed (Sorting by product_viewed)
4. Sorting by Specific Subcategory
```

All the results should display with pagination. This is all right if i first get the result. But if i walk with pagination links all the condition data is lost and the query fetches the results without any condition. How can i manage This situation. Please i dont need Code i need hints and suggestions. The other thing is that i am using Codeigniter's pagination class.

EDITED

Here is my Model Method i am using

```
public function getProductsList($per_page=5,$page=0)
{
    $info   =   $this->input->post();

    if(isset($info['type']))
    {
        $type   =   $info['type'];

        if($type == 'most_wanted'){
            $where      =   " AND sale_wanted = 1";
            $order_by   =   " ORDER BY ldc.added_date desc";
        }else if($type == 'most_viewed'){
            $where      =   " ";
            $order_by   =   " ORDER BY ldc.product_viewed desc";            
        }else{
            $where      =   " ";
            $order_by   =   " ORDER BY ldc.added_date desc";                
        }
    }else if(isset($info['sale_wanted'])   AND isset($info['subcategory_id'])){
        $sale_wanted        =   $info['sale_wanted'];
        $subcategory_id =   $info['subcategory_id'];
        $where      =   " AND sale_wanted = $sale_wanted AND ldc.subcategory_id = $subcategory_id";
        $order_by   =   " ORDER BY  ldc.added_date desc";   
    }else if(isset($info['keyword'])){
            $keyword    =   $info['keyword'];
            $search_type    =   $info['search_type'];
            $where      =   " AND ldc.$search_type like '$keyword%'";
            $order_by   =   " ";        
    }else{
            $where      =   " ";
            $order_by   =   " ";            
    }           

    $num    =   0;

    if($page != 0){
        $num    =   ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
    }


    $sql_query  =   "
                SELECT 
                    ldc.id,
                    ldc.product_name,
                    ldc.product_viewed,
                    DATE_FORMAT(ldc.added_date, '%m/%d/%Y') as added_date,
                    ifnull(dc.name,'Unknown') as category,
                    dpi.product_image           
                FROM default_products AS ldc
                LEFT JOIN default_manufacturers as dm ON dm.id = ldc.manufacturer
                LEFT JOIN default_category as dc ON dc.category_id = ldc.category_id
                LEFT JOIN ((select product_id , product_image from default_product_images group by product_id) as dpi)
                    ON dpi.product_id = ldc.id
                WHERE   approved = 1
                $where
                $order_by
                LIMIT $num,$per_page
        ";

    $query  =   $this->db->query($sql_query);
    return  $query->result();
}
```

Comment: are you going display all 4 kinds in different tables..........

Comment: no i have only a single view(table) and i dont want to repeat my code

Comment: In single table you will display all the products in normal when user selects those conditions they results will change as per condition. am i right......

Comment: can you add the code which you are using for retrieving and display in the view file........

Comment: I think you asked this question previously and you only posted the answer also. Now are you facing again the same problem........

Comment: Yes i posted and found a way with session but this doesn't seem to be ideal solution

Answer (score 1):

i would highly recommend these two Free tutorials on codeigniter pagination -
video tutorials, working sample code ( might need to update code to CI 2.1 ), and even some helpful info in the comments.

CodeIgniter from Scratch: Displaying & Sorting Tabular Data
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-displaying-sorting-tabular-data/

CodeIgniter from Scratch: Search Results without Query Strings
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-search-results-without-query-strings-2/